# How can I set my own typeface in AChartEngine renderer?

Tags: android, fonts, achartengine

As you might know, you can use your own font in your specific android UI like following:

```
    myNewFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myown.ttf");
    TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleFunc);
    label.setTypeface(myNewFace);
```

Now, I need to apply this font to AChartEngine but can't figure out how.

I can see DefaultRenderer has a method

```
 setTextTypeface(java.lang.String typefaceName, int style)
```

But this method can't be used with custom font. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

**UPDATE**

To answer my own question, there is simply no way to set custom font in achartengine without changing source code. So I added simple methods setTypeface and getTypeface to DefaultRenderer and changed a couple of lines of code in XYChart accordingly. Voila, it's now working.

Comment: could you please post the changes you made to the source code? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can contribute the code to the AChartEngine community by creating a patch and adding it as an issue?

**Update**: There is a `setTextTypeface()` method that was recently added to `DefaultRenderer` that you can use for this.